# How to make my fluid animation more realistic

Tags: fluid-simulation

So I'm trying to make Fluid sim which has 3 shots and the scene where I'm stuck is where chocolate milk drops in glass and Ice Cubes clash with the flow, I'm trying to make it like a reference picture and Playing with settings but I'm no where near how it should look like

[image: How I wanna make it like]

[image: Sim with 2 Sub Div]

[image: Sim with 3 Sub Div]

[image: sim with 4 sub div]

[image: my sim setup and settings]

Does anyone has any link or any idea on how I can improve it

Comment: I remember this question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/247680/107598 maybe it helps you? I'm not sure if you can combine the pouring with a splash easily.

Comment: @Blunder thanks a lot man, I played with that setting for few hours and now I am getting the splash I wanted, without your reply I couldn't have got closer to my aim